# Xamarin forms Sqlite WinPhone SQLitePCL.raw' threw an exception System.TypeInitializationException

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8.1, xamarin.forms

Im trying to get a Xamarin forms sqlite up an runnig.

it works fine for Android and iOS, but for windows i get this error.
I'm target the solutions for windows phone 8.1 and using Xamarin forms 1.5(I can't upgrade it)

I been following [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/databases/#Windows_Phone_Project) sample from Xamarin

```
public class SQLite_WinPhone : ISQLite
    {
        public SQLite_WinPhone() { }
        protected override SQLite.SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
        {
            var sqliteFilename = "TODO.db3";
            string path = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, sqliteFilename);
            // Create the connection
            var conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(path);
            // Return the database connection
            return conn;
        }
    }
```

but so far no luck.

have any of you out there bump into this before?

Answer (score 0):

Android and iOS ship with a SQLite runtime, Windows doesn't.

You need to add:

1. The SQLitePCL.raw package to your Windows app.
2. The current c++ runtime package to your windows app

   - Rightclick on references in solution explorer, select Windows > Extensions > *Microsoft Visual c++ Runtime Package*

Comment: Indeed that is true, but as i said in the question, i follow the xamarin guide for this, which explain that you need to do this. so i did. but thanks anyway

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the c++ runtime hint on that tutorial. What does the exceptions message say?